Wifi option comepletely dissappeared on my ubuntu
So I have recently started using ubuntu 22.04LTS version(on VM virtualbox). Initially the wireless wifi was working fine but suddenly a few days the wifi icon option completely dissappeared and I am not connected to any networks.Its showing only the ethernet option is available but when I connect my ethernet cable  I don't seem to get internet. I tried few fixes that I saw  on the internet but none of them seemed to work.I thought maybe the network access NAT that I used on vm virtualbox was issue and changed it to bridged and few others but none of them seem to have worked. Even if I need to install additional drivers, I am unable to connect to the internet for that. I hope someone can help me out with this issue.

If this is a VM, your wifi card isn't exposed to the VM directly unless you unassigin it from your host machine.  What does lsusb and lspci show on the command line?  If the wifi card isn't there then the issue is it's not assigned to your VM dedicated.  NAT and Bridged will only show up on the VM as "LAN" and not Wifi, you won't actually have wifi on your VM unless you have a dedicated wifi card passed through that isn't in use by the host (like an external USB wifi adapter)

Actually I tried a fix that I found, the internet is back which I can see from nmcli command. lsusb and lspci both show the host bridge and bus devices. But the issue is the wifi symbol isn't still back, when I type the nmcli Dev wifi list, I do not see anything. It is connected to the wifi adress which it was already connected to previously but I cannot connect to any other wifi addresses as there is no symbol and the list.

You won't ever SEE wifi on your VM unless you have a wifi adapter sent directly to the VM and not used by the host computer itself.  If it's not visible, and you don't see anything in lspci or lsusb for the wifi adapter, then you're never going to see wifi.  I think you seeing 'wifi' is a fluke not actually accurate.

No I never used any extranal usb adapters. I could see the local wifi netoworks previously at the top right. But now I am unable to see any of them. I'm pretty sure I am connected to the internet my firefox is running. But unlike previously I am unable to see any of the wifi networks or the option itself. I don't understand how that is a fluke? Because it was normally running for months .
